# Is one allowed to say shehecheyanu over meeting with a friend during the nine days?

Tags: nine-days, three-weeks, shehecheyanu

From http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/144573/jewish/Three-Weeks.htm , one learns that one should not taste new fruits during the three weeks in order not to have to say  shehecheyanu.

> During this period, we lessen the extent of our rejoicing. We don't:
>
> Recite the Shehecheyanu blessing. Thus, we do not wear new clothing or
>   eat fruit which we have not yet eaten this season so that we will not
>   be required to recite Shehecheyanu.

It appears to me that this prohibition also apply to blessing over old friends.

From http://www.torahmusings.com/2011/02/reuniting-with-friends/

> The Talmud teaches that one who hasn’t seen a good friend in over a
>   month should recite a special blessing – the shehecheyanu blessing-
>   upon seeing them again.[1] A “friend” in this context refers to a
>   person with whom one is exceptionally close, and whose presence brings
>   one great happiness.[2] In the event that an entire year has gone by
>   since one last saw such a friend, one recites the blessing “mechaye
>   hameitim“.  Similarly, one also recites the shehecheyanu blessing when
>   being personally received by a great person, particularly a renowned
>   Torah scholar, who is rarely accessible for private audiences.

Should one go out of one's way to avoid seeing good friends one has not seen in a long time during the three weeks and/or nine days?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61256/shehechiyanu-for-baby-girl-during-the-3-weeks-9-days#comment166604_61258 I happen to know someone who said Shehechiyanu for this reason on Tisha b'Av itself once when he ran into an old friend.